# Changing pandas class variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, pandas

I'm making use of the pandas.tseries.holiday module and have had an issue with the AbstractHolidayCalendar class within this module. The use is to obtain a calendar that accounts for all bank holidays/weekends in the UK when rolling forward business days.

My existing code (taken from another user) is:

```
class EnglandAndWalesHolidayCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
rules = [Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, observance=next_monday),
         GoodFriday,
         EasterMonday,
         Holiday('Early May bank holiday',
             month=5, day=1, offset=DateOffset(weekday=MO(1))),
         Holiday('Spring bank holiday',
             month=5, day=31, offset=DateOffset(weekday=MO(-1))),
         Holiday('Summer bank holiday',
             month=8, day=31, offset=DateOffset(weekday=MO(-1))),
         Holiday('Christmas Day', month=12, day=25, observance=next_monday),
         Holiday('Boxing Day',
             month=12, day=26, observance=next_monday_or_tuesday)]
```

In the pandas module mentioned, I see the following:

```
class AbstractHolidayCalendar(object):
    """
    Abstract interface to create holidays following certain rules.
    """
    __metaclass__ = HolidayCalendarMetaClass
    rules = []
    start_date = Timestamp(datetime(1970, 1, 1))
    end_date = Timestamp(datetime(2030, 12, 31))
    _cache = None
```

However when adding

```
end_date = Timestamp(datetime(2080, 12, 31))
```

To my defined class it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to adjust the end date without directly changing the pandas module?
Thanks

Comment: `AbstractHolidayCalendar.end_date = Timestamp(datetime(2080, 12, 31))`?

Comment: Yes that works! I don't understand why that didn't need to be done for "rules" though?